# Get Google Map V1 Key android

Tags: android, google-maps

Since last few months I was making an application which incorporates Google Maps, and I was using `Google Maps V1` in it. Yesterday I formatted my system, so the key which I was earlier using `API V1` for the *Google Maps* is not working now for the development process.

Now I am trying to make the key for the API v1 again, but I am unable to do so. Can anyone please help me out. Whether I have to shift on `Google Map API V2` now ??

I have generated one key using API V2 also. This is also not working. My code is written for Google Maps V1.

Comment: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

Comment: Which code that you have written in Maps V1 and is not working in V2? What is the functionality you are expecting in V2?

Comment: I suggest you switch to map api v2

Comment: I have made my application with google maps v1 5 months back, but now I want some changes in it. Now suggest me what to do.

Comment: I had the same problem as you, an user of stackoverflow advised me to contact the google group developers, but it did not work for me. I suggest you to use the map version 2, it is really good and it will save a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions

Comment: Restore your keys from your backup. All serious programmers maintain backups.

Comment: I have my backup key, but it is not working for development purpose on my system. It is working with the apk's ( not for the one which I deploying from system using data cable)

Comment: Can I still upload a new update of my app with v1 into play store (I have the map key already)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good and tricky answer from my side too.

**As you have your own key ( but because you do not have the debug.keystore for the previous configuration), so you cant use your key. In this case you can do the below task :**

Take the debug.keystore and debug API key for Google maps API V1 from anyone else system who has done google maps v1 and use that key for your development purpose, once it is complete and you have checked it, deploy it with the key which you already have for the application.

Let me know if you have any queries ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps API v1 is now deprecated so no more keys unfortunately...

> Note: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially
>   deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th,
>   2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this
>   version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1.
>   However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and
>   new developers are encouraged to use Google Maps Android API v2.

from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

Answer (score 1):

If you somehow had managed to save a copy of your debug.keystore file.. you need not have to use the Google Maps Android API v2..

- Now no other option but to use the new API... Give it a try they have made things easier now.

Comment: Thanks aditya for the support